# npm express not able to get object from request in backend

Tags: rest, npm, angular-cli

I followed [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/mean-app-with-angular-2-and-the-angular-cli) tutorial and created an app with frontend/backend side in angular.

I want to communicate with json via rest calls to backend. The frontend and backend are working and I am able to call the methods from backend.

On the frontend side I am sending a hero object to backend but on the backend side the body.hero object is undefined.

frontend:

```
update(hero: Hero): Promise<Hero> {
      const url = `${this.heroesUrl}/hero/update/${hero.id}`;
      console.info('update url: '+url);
      return this.http.put(url, JSON.stringify(hero), {headers: this.headers})
        .toPromise()
        .then(() => hero).catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

backend:

```
router.put('/heroes/hero/update/:id', (req, res) => {
  let id = req.params.id; // 12
  let z = req.body.params;
  console.info("body: "+z);
  let name = JSON.parse(req.body.hero).name;
  console.info("saving hero: "+name+" with id: "+id);
  client.query("update heroes set heroname=$2 where id_pk=$1)", [h, name]);
  res.send(JSON.stringify("ok"));
});
```

exception:

```
body: [object Object]
SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at Object.parse (native)
    at router.put (C:\Users\Magamet\Documents\GitHub\angular-start-app\server\routes\api.js:64:19)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Magamet\Documents\GitHub\angular-start-app\node_modules\express\lib\ro
uter\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\Magamet\Documents\GitHub\angular-start-app\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Magamet\Documents\GitHub\angular-start-app\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:
3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Magamet\Documents\GitHub\angular-start-app\node_modules\express\lib\ro
uter\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\Magamet\Documents\GitHub\angular-start-app\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at param (C:\Users\Magamet\Documents\GitHub\angular-start-app\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:354:14)
    at param (C:\Users\Magamet\Documents\GitHub\angular-start-app\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:365:14)
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Magamet\Documents\GitHub\angular-start-app\node_modules\express\lib\router\inde
x.js:410:3)
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to send hero obj to backend in json? How could I read the hero object on the backend side?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It seems your hero object is being sent as a JSON string to the backend, meaning that req.body.hero is already parsed by your router. This means that you are parsing an already parsed JSON string. You need only access it like any other js object:

```
let name = req.body.hero.name;
```

Comment: but then it says `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

Comment: Are you requiring body-parser?

Comment: I weren't but I have added this: `const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())` but it still doesn't work same error as before

Comment: Have you tried adding 'dataType: "json"' to your parameters of your ajax call?

Comment: this is my header that I have defined 
   `private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});`
I can access `req.body.name` directly without the hero cause the hero does not exist on server side

Comment: Try adding `dataType: "json"` to that header. It should change the way data is received by your route so that you won't need to use JSON.parse.